# How can I set state on individual elements in a mapped function using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am aware that a similar question has been asked. But I'm still struggling to wrap my mind around it. Basically I'm mapping thru some data - and when the user clicks on 'add more', it basically shows a copy of the previous element. And I have a tooltip - when the user hovers over or clicks on the tooltip it shows a message. Unfortunately the tooltip shows up for ALL mapped elements ( and I want to show it only for the current one ).

The problem is that I'm using a ChakraUI library, and I need to pass a true/false to display a tooltip. I have found some answers suggesting to pass index into state, but I can only pass 'true' or 'false' which makes me wonder how to pass index to a boolean state variable.

Here's the code - any tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I feel preetty clueless on how to figure this out.

`isOpen={}`
is reponsible for displaying ( or not ) the information within the tooltip

```
  const [stackableTooltip, setStackableTooltip] = useState(false)

return (
<>
{data.map(index => {
                        <Flex>
                          <Tooltip
                            label={t('tooltip.stackable')}
                            isOpen={stackableTooltip}
                          >
                            <img
                              src={stackable}
                              onMouseEnter={() => setStackableTooltip(true)}
                              onMouseLeave={() => setStackableTooltip(false)}
                              onClick={() => setStackableTooltip((open) => !open)}
                            ></img>
                          </Tooltip>
                        </Flex>
})}
</>
)
```

In  short I need a way to add index to the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move it to the custom component

```
export default function  ImageContainer () {
  const [stackableTooltip, setStackableTooltip] = useState(false)

  return  ( <Tooltip label={t('tooltip.stackable')} isOpen= {stackableTooltip}>
    <img
      src={stackable}
      onMouseEnter={() => setStackableTooltip(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setStackableTooltip(false)}
      onClick={() => setStackableTooltip((open) => !open)}
    ></img>
  </Tooltip>)

}
```

In the main component just call this function

```
return ( <>
  {data.map(index =>  
           <Flex>
            <ImageContainer />
           </Flex>
  )}
 </>
)
```